# Ставится ли запятая? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Как всегда, автор пособия, по которому я занимаюсь, добавил в тест случай, который не разбирал в объяснении темы.

> Похолодало и на душе стало беспокойно.

Из Интернета (снова спасибо М. М. Бароновой за обучение читателей её пособия самостоятельному поиску недостающей информации) стало понятно: если в безличном предложении нет синонимичных слов, перед союзом ставится запятая. И их нет. Однако Баронова считает, что запятая не нужна.
Пожалуйста, объясните: кто прав?

Если что, до этого она считала, что в предложении "И старые, и молодые работали в поле" запятая не нужна, потому что это фразеологизм по типу "и стар и млад".

Comment: Вы пишете: "Однако, Баронова считает, что запятая нужна". Наверное, пропустили "не"?

Comment: Да, что не нужна. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: The Practice Of Chaos, не забывайте, пожалуйста, отмечать все полезные ответы и вопросы стрелочкой вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой.

Answer (score 3):

В предложении *И старые и молодые работали в поле* запятая может отсутствовать по следующему [правилу](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112) (см. § 26):

> ...При однородных членах предложения, образующих тесное смысловое
> единство, запятая может не ставиться: Кругом было и светло и зелено
> (Т.); И днем и ночью кот ученый все ходит по цепи кругом (П.)

В предложении же *Похолодало, и на душе стало беспокойно* я не вижу оснований для того, чтобы удалять запятую. Если Баронова полагает, что её не должно быть, пусть аргументирует.
Впрочем, я не нашёл, где бы декларировалось отсутствие запятой. Возможно, просто опечатка в ответах к тесту.

Answer (score 1):

> *Похолодало и на душе стало беспокойно.*

> Из Интернета (снова спасибо М. М. Бароновой за обучение читателей её пособия самостоятельному поиску недостающей информации) стало понятно: если в безличном предложении нет синонимичных слов, перед союзом ставится запятая. И их нет. Однако Баронова считает, что запятая не нужна.

Странная дама эта М. М. Баронова. Запятая, конечно, нужна: это сложносочинённое предложение (ССП). А «безличность» здесь не играет абсолютно никакой роли.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Решение**

***ПохолодАло, и на душе стало беспокойно.***  Неоднородные отношения, взаимообусловленные. Явно присутствует пауза/запятая, в одну фразу не прочитаешь.

Сравнить: *Пошёл дождь, потом мокрый снег, похолодало, и мне стало не по себе.* [Д. И. Саврасов. Таежные были и небылицы (2003-2008)]

**2. Пояснение**

(1) ***Холодно и сыро. Промозгло  и мутно, туманно и вьюжно.***

**Запятой нет, синонимичных слов тоже**.  А что есть: одинаковая форма сказуемого, одна и та же  ситуация. Односоставные предложения **однородного вида**.

(2) ***Смеркалось, и в комнате стало темно. Вечерело,  и становилось прохладно. Было тихо, светло, и чуть подмораживало.***

А здесь разные ситуации, разные грамматические формы глагола. Односоставные предложения **неоднородного вида.**

**3.** У Розенталя эта тема **раскрыта недостаточно**, поэтому на одни **синонимичные слова** ориентироваться нельзя. [§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133):

(5) односоставные безличные предложения, **имеющие синонимичные слова**: Необходимо рассмотреть авторские заявки и надо срочно составить по ним заключения.

Но при отсутствии синонимичных слов запятая между двумя безличными предложениями перед союзом ***и*** ставится: Нету чудес, и мечтать о них нечего (М.); Между тем совсем рассвело, и надо было опять выходить в море (Кат.)